# Date Object in node.js has some weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I was testing around with NODE for a while now and I experienced a strange behaviour of JS `Date()` object. The `getDay()` and `getMonth()` function are returning incorrect results. I thought I messed up somewhat somewhere in my app, but I tested in the console as well and still the same behaviour. Here is the my log of the console:

```
$ node
> var currentDate = new Date();
undefined
> currentDate
Wed Jun 19 2013 13:54:20 GMT+0200 (CEST)
> currentDate.getDay()
3
> currentDate.getMonth()
5
```

it seems to off 'a bit'.

I do not now what' s going on and web-research did not help me as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`getDay` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of week, so 3 means wednesday.

The [`getMonth` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) returns the zero based month, so 5 means june.

Comment: Ok then I just miss-understood these methods

Comment: +1 - and just to be clear, getDay is also zero based:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Ok I should (and will) be using `getDate()` instead of `getDay()`